# How to show Select2 selected values under the select as a List

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap-4, jquery-select2

I want to show Select2 selected values below the dropdown as a List.
[image: Similar to this]

This is not Select 2 but a custom select from a 3rd party site.
Till now I have no Idea how to move the selections to a different container.

Here is my existing Select2 [image: The General Multiselect]

Would be great if can get direction on where to start.

Comment: What is that library ? are you using jQuery ?

Comment: Yes I am using Latest jQuery

Comment: Images aren't helpful on SO to get an answer. Have you tried any code? If yes, please post the code and create a snippet. If not, I'd suggest you try it first and then post the snippet. And that requirement of yours should be fairly simple.

Comment: Did you found a solution eventually for this?

Comment: @RalphJansen Yes Indeed, I developed this myself, here's a screenshot https://dj1gbnpej5rmb.cloudfront.net/items/3M0L3a093r1x2Z3N1c05/Image%202019-03-15%20at%203.34.07%20PM.png

Comment: Looks nice! Not really the same as your image above but I understand what you did. I'm searching for exactly the thing as above. I hoped for a native configuration/extension of select2 for this.

Comment: I couldn't find anything related to what I was initially looking for, I am using select2 but to render the list below the select I had to use on change event to regenerate the list, at the moment I didn't have any other choice rather than code it myself, here's a gist for same https://gist.github.com/pankaj-sj/51374d20c92e157da92c041b5560e243
Let me know if it helped or if you find any better option to do this. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some R&D I was able to do it with below code.

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
    var $source_select = jQuery('#source_id');
    var $source_display_container = jQuery('.vendor_container');
    $source_select.select2({
        placeholder: 'Select Sources',
        allowClear: true,
        closeOnSelect: false,
    }).on('change', function() {
        var $selected = $(this).find('option:selected');
        var $container = $source_display_container;

        var $list = $('<div class="content">');
        $selected.each(function(k, value) {
            var $source_html_row = $('<div>').addClass('row');
            $source_name = $(value).text();
            $source_id = $(value).attr('data-vendor_id');
            $source_html_row.append(getSourceNameColumn($source_name, value, $source_id));
            $source_html_row.append(getCPIColumn($source_id, value));
            $source_html_row.append(getQuotaColumn($source_id, value));
            $source_html_row.append(getScreenerColumn($source_id,value));
            $source_html_row.append(getQuotaAssignmentColumn($source_id, value));
            $source_html_row.append(getRemoveColumn(value));

            $list.append($source_html_row);
        });
        $container.html('').append($list);
    }).trigger('change');
});
```